# Extending matlab code for a single file to multiple files

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a Matlab problem, thanks in advance for your help!

I have a code for a csv file, at the end of which, I get a value, let's call it the DesiredValue.

I have a folder with many csv files named as: Cells_1A1,  Cells_2A1,  Cells_3A1, Cells_1B1,  Cells_2B1,  Cells_3B1.

Here, 1 2 3 in the beginning refer to the time point.

I want to extend my code so that
1. The code generates DesiredValue for each file
2. It takes the mean of all files whose names start with 1 (Here- Cells_1A1, Cells_1B1) and start with 2 (Here- Cells_2A1, Cells_2B1) and computes the standard deviation and plots it.
3. How to store this matrix outside the loop so that its value isnt over written - because I have multiple such folders and eventually I want to compare plots for different folders on the same graph.

My code is:

```
%**************************************************************************
% Reading the csv files generated by CellProfiler
%**************************************************************************
%**************************************************************************
% Reading data for each cell
%**************************************************************************

A = csvread('Cells_2C1.csv',1,0);
XCell = A(:,3);                % x coordinate of centroid
YCell = A(:,4)                % y coordinate of centroid


%**************************************************************************
% Reading data for spheroid
%**************************************************************************

% JAREK : this will never be empty.

B = csvread('Spheroid_2C1.csv',1,0);
XSpheroid= B(:,4);              % x coordinate of centroid
YSpheroid= B(:,5);              % y coordinate of centroid
AreaSpheroid = B(:,3);          % Area of spheroid

%**************************************************************************
% Radius of the uniform circle centered at the centroid of the spheroid 
% with the same area as the spheroid
%**************************************************************************

UniformRadius = sqrt(AreaSpheroid*(7/22));

%**************************************************************************
% Distance between centroid of spheroid and the centroid of each cell
%**************************************************************************

XSpheroidResized = repmat(XSpheroid,size(XCell)); % make dimension of spheroid coordinates
YSpheroidResized = repmat(YSpheroid,size(YCell)); % matrices same as cells' coordinates matrices 

X = XCell - XSpheroidResized; % X coordinates of the distance
XSquare = X.*X;

Y = YCell - YSpheroidResized; % y coordinate of the distance
YSquare = Y.*Y;

DistanceSquare = XSquare + YSquare;
DistanceBetweenCentroids = sqrt(DistanceSquare); 

%**************************************************************************
% Distance between boundary of uniform circle and centroid each cell
%**************************************************************************
repmat(UniformRadius, size(XCell); % making dimension of uniform radius same as that of 
                                    % cells' coordinates matrices

DistanceUniformBoundaryAndCell = abs(DistanceBetweenCentroids - repmat(UniformRadius, size(XCell)))


%**************************************************************************
% Distance of the cell furthest away from the boundary of the regular
% circle
%**************************************************************************




DesiredDistance = max(DistanceUniformBoundaryAndCell);
```

Comment: You will be interested in the [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) function and and a [`for` loop](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html). After that, StackOverflow is not a code writing service, so you'll have to try some things on your own to figure it out. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi! Yes, I used dir to list the names of the files, but how does one introduce a for loop within the file names - if the file names are like Cell_1B1, Cell_1A1...Cell_5B1, Cell_5A1? Where can I iterate it?
Thanks!

Comment: `dir` returns a structure containing the filenames. To access them, you do `dirlisting = dir; dirlisting(1).name` will show then name of the first file. You can use that in your loop.

Comment: I don't see results being overwritten anywhere. In general the solution for that would be storing them in a matrix or cell array.